# Why "Detect Face" in MLKIT make memory leak?

Tags: android, performance, firebase-mlkit

I writing a app about camera, with each image from camera, I pass it to class `BarCode` or `DetectFace` to detect barcode or face. But I have a problem about memory leak when I use `DetectFace`.

It is safe if I use `BarCode`:

```
override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        imageOnFrame = reader.acquireNextImage()
        barcode = BarCode(this@MainActivity, imageOnFrame, getRotation("0"))
        barcode!!.run()
        barcode = null
        imageOnFrame.close()
    }
```

But if i use `DetectFace`, this make memory leak:

```
override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
        imageOnFrame = reader.acquireNextImage()
        detectFace = DetectFace(this@MainActivity, imageOnFrame, getRotation("0"))
        detectFace!!.run()
        detectFace = null  
        imageOnFrame.close()
    }
```

This is class `DetectFace`:

```
class DetectFace(private val context: Context, private val image: Image, private val rotation: Int) {

    private val option = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setModeType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE_MODE)
            .setLandmarkType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .setClassificationType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .setMinFaceSize(0.01f)
            .build()

    fun run(){
        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(this.image, rotation)
        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getVisionFaceDetector(option)

        detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    // code ..
                }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    // code ..
                }
        this.image.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly due to that the images sent to ML Kit are too fast that it could not process in time, and the memory usage increases. We will provide a way to handle it properly inside ML Kit. In the mean time, you could throttle the images sent to ML Kit.

For example, the ML Kit quick start sample app does the image throttling here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/VisionProcessorBase.java#L49

Comment: I did so, it was faster, but it was still slower than the speed I wanted

Comment: any update for this problem? the link above showing 404 to me